# Why am I getting a deallocated memory call when I call UICollectionViewCell dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that contains custom UICollectionViewCells (TestReceiptCell is the class name).

I was not having any problems getting the UICollectionView to appear and load the custom cells when the custom cells only contained a UILabel.

I then added a UITableView via IB into the TestReceiptCell NIB file.  I set a referencing outlet in TestReceiptCell.h for the UITableView and synthesized in the .m file.  I set the delegate and datasource for the UITableView to the ViewController containing the UICollectionView.

Now when running the app I get a EXC_ BAD_ ACCESS exception in this block on the third line:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TestReceiptCell";
    TestReceiptCell *cell = (TestReceiptCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; //exception thrown here
    return cell;
}
```

I ran the Zombie Instrument test and found that the deallocated memory call originates here.  This is my first time using that instrument so I am not exactly sure how to investigate from here.

For reference, here are some more relevant parts of the code:

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TestReceiptCell" bundle:nil]  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TestReceiptCell"];

    // Setup flowlayout
    myCollectionViewFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [myCollectionViewFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(310, 410)];
    [myCollectionViewFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.myCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:myCollectionViewFlowLayout];
    self.myCollectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
}
```

I am implementing the UITableView datasource and delegate methods in the ViewController.m file as well but I am not sure if the problem lies here given the origination of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"eventCell"];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"eventCell"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

UPDATE:

I am able to get this to run if I change cellForItemAtIndexPath to:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TestReceiptCell";
    //TestReceiptCell *cell = (TestReceiptCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    TestReceiptCell *cell = [NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"TestReceiptCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
    return cell;
}
```

However, I am not dequeuing cells and know this is not the correct way.  There seems to be an issue somewhere in the initWithFrame method that gets called when dequeueReusableCellWithResueIdentifier creates a new cell.  Here is that method currently:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestReceiptCell" owner:self options:nil];
        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }
        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }
        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT:

If I do not select a delegate or a datasource for the tableview, the collectionview with tableviews will load.  Something in attaching the delegate/datasource to File's Owner is causing the error.

Comment: It is possible that you mingled between `TestReceiptCell` and `FullReceiptCell` for the collection view cells ?

Comment: ah - careless question asking on my end... forgot to repaste the correct code. I have revised the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register a UINib for cell reuse, dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: is what calls instantiateWithOwner:options: on the UINib that you registered. Whatever it passes for owner, is what becomes the File's Owner outlet in your nib.

It appears that you are expecting the File's Owner to be the UICollectionView, but I don't think that it is.

Even if it were, I don't think you should use the UICollectionView for the delegate of the UITableView contained within each collection cell. That would require your UICollectionView to keep track of the tableViews and contents within each cell.

I'd suggest setting the delegate of the contained tableView to the collection cell itself and have each cell manage its own tableview.

EDIT:

You can define a delegate protocol for your collection view cells to communicate the relevant table view events to the collection view. With this approach, you would set the delegate property you define for each collection cell in the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath method of your collection view datasource.

When the user, for example, selects an item from the table, you can call the cell delegate to inform the collection view which item was selected.

This approach allows you to abstract the fact that your collection cell is using a table view to display the cell information. Later, if you decide you want to use, for example, an embedded UICollectionView to display those items, the delegate protocol can remain unchanged and you can isolate your changes to the collection cell.

Comment: Thanks.  I solved this by setting the delegate and datasource for each table in the 'cellForItemAtIndexPath' method in my ViewController's .m file.  It works but I would like to design efficiently. I have two 'UICollectionViews' in the same 'ViewController', one containing UITableViews in its cells.  The reason I do not manage those 'UITableViews' in the collection cell is because in response to selection and deselection of cells in the 'UITableViews', changes need to occur in the 2nd 'UICollectionView'.  Knowing that, is it still possible to set the delegate to the 'UICollectionViewCell'?

Comment: Sure. I added some additional explanation for one way you might solve this issue. Hope that it is helpful.

Comment: This is super helpful.  I have already reworked it so that the `UITableViews` delegate and datasource are the `UICollectionCell` they are contained in (rather than the view controller).  I believe I understand in principle the delegate protocol you explained above but implementation will surely prove to be a challenge.  I will let you know how it goes.  Thanks.

Comment: got the delegate protocol up and running!  Thanks for your help... I feel as if this was a big breakthrough in understanding how objects communicate in objective-c.

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help.

Comment: By the way, is there any information on what, exactly, "it passes for owner"?